# Copying text that can be pasted as a table in word, excel, etc

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy-paste, richtext

I'm not sure if this is considered converting the text data to rich text or not, but I want to take a series of inputs, either from a table or a series of divs (the latter is what I'm using), and place it into a format that can be easily pasted into Word, Outlook or Excel as a table.

I haven't figured out how I'm going to cycle through the list to get all possible entries just yet, but in pseudo code, the following is what I'm looking to do:

```
var currentLine;    // This is the current line used in the following loop:
for (<each list item found>) {
    currentLine = `${box1A} ${box1B}`;
    <append currentLine to a new line in a textarea element>;
}
<select the text in the textarea element>;
document.execCommand('copy');
```

Ultimately, the javascript that I will actually use will result in new lines being pasted into a new row (this is good), however, the two strings will be in the came cell.  See the following example:

```
+------------+-------+
| box1A box1B|       |
+------------+-------+
| box2A box2B|       |
+------------+-------+
| box3A box3B|       |
+------------+-------+
| etc.. etc..|       |
+------------+-------+
```

How can I ensure that box1A will end up being in one cell, and box1B will automatically be pasted into a second cell on the same row?  See the following example of what I want:

```
+-------+-------+
| box1A | box1B |
+-------+-------+
| box2A | box2B |
+-------+-------+
| box3A | box3B |
+-------+-------+
| etc.. | etc.. |
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my findings so far, values are separated by tabs.  In the example I provided, in order for `boxA` and `boxB` to align to different cells on the same row, you can use the following setup for the string:

```
var row = `${box1A}\t${box1B}\n${box2A}\t${box2B}\n${box3A}\t${box3B}`
```

The end result of the above line would yield, once copied onto the clipboard & pasted into Excel:

```
+-------+-------+
| box1A | box1B |
+-------+-------+
| box2A | box2B |
+-------+-------+
| box3A | box3B |
+-------+-------+
```

The `\t` denotes a [Horizontal Tabulator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp), and will result in automatically entering the next value into the next cell.

The `\n` denotes a [New Line](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp), and will result in automatically entering the next value into the next cell.